# How to automatically update version of application in Terraform project when application release is made?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, circleci

We have a number of applications that are built and released via CircleCI. 
But we deploy these applications using Terraform, which is a separate repository. 
What I want to do is automatically update the version of an application in the Terraform project such that a build for the Terraform project is triggered and the application is automatically deployed.

Is there a way I can easily update the version of the application in the Terraform repo?

Comment: Is there a reason why the application's repo can't have the Terraform code to be able to deploy itself?

Comment: Multiple teams use the same Terraform codebase to deploy onto the cluster. Not saying this is necessarily the right way, but that's how things are at the moment.

Comment: It's hard to answer this question as is but I have some shared Terraform modules that each service can use to deploy their application by giving a minimal amount of config (service name and environment being the only required things, others can be overridden if necessary). Would that work for you?

Comment: Would you have some examples @ydaetskcoR?